# How to get the partial String from the string

Tags: sql, postgresql, substring

how can I extract the numerical values between `/` and `.html`?

```
http://www.site.com/prod/bunch-of-seo-text-of-different-length/12345687.html
http://www.site.com/prod/bunch-of-seo-text-of-different-length/12345688.html
http://www.site.com/prod/bunch-of-seo-text-of-different-length/12345688.html
```

I tried this, but I don't know about the syntax

```
SUBSTRING(link FROM '%/%' FOR '%.html%')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not a postgresql guy, but it looks like it has some built-in regex functions. See [PostgreSQL Matching Functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/functions-matching.html) and find the section where it describes the `regexp_matches` function. `regexp_matches` returns an array ({}).

```
SELECT regexp_matches(link, '([0-9]+)\.html$');
```

Combine this with a `unnest` see [PostgreSQL Arrays](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/arrays.html):

```
SELECT unnest(SELECT regexp_matches(link, '([0-9]+)\.html$')) as matches;
```

Comment: it is giving me weird `{result}` and I am not sure how to get rid of `{` and `}`

Comment: @Andrew, i have no idea if my edit will work since i have only SQL experience and not postgresql, but the idea is that regexp_matches returns an array, you need to then access that array, or translate it into table rows, i attempted to turn it into table rows.

Comment: No need for unnest: `select (regexp_matches(link, '[0-9]+'))[1]
from urls;`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, using [1] makes assumptions about the data returned. The attempt with unnest is a way to maximize flexibility and not assume that [1] will always be the data you want. I suppose in this specific case [1] is safe.

Comment: No need fore `regexp_matches()` either, that's not a good fit for the question.

Answer (score 2):

The question is:

> how can I extract the numerical values between / and .html?

And a proper answer is:

```
SELECT substring(link, '/(\d+)\.html')
```

`\d` .. the class shorthand for `[[:digit:]]` which is equivalent to [0-9]
 `+` .. one or more of the preceding atom
`()` .. parenthesis capture the match
`\.` .. dot has to be escaped to loose its special meaning

Test:

```
WITH x(link) AS (
    VALUES
     ('http://www.site.com/prod/bunch-of-text-of-different-length/12345687.html')
    ,('http://www.site.com/prod/bunch-of-text/12345688.html')
    ,('http://www.site2.com/prod/123/text-of-di456fferent-89-len/12345688.html')
    )
SELECT substring(link, '/(\d+)\.html') FROM x;
```

[`regexp_matches()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER) is meant for capturing multiple matches and is not a good choice for this.

Comment: Brandstetter, I was not aware that substring can take a regex. I agree, your answer is much better suited for this question.

Answer (score 0):

This snippet will give you the filename of any url:

```
SELECT REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(REPLACE('http://www.somewhere.com/folder/page.html', '\', '/')), 1, CHARINDEX('/', REVERSE(REPLACE('http://www.somewhere.com/folder/page.html', '\', '/'))) - 1)) as PageName
```

**Output:**

> page.html

Or, if you are passing in the url as an nvarchar variable:

```
SELECT REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(REPLACE(@Url, '\', '/')), 1, CHARINDEX('/', REVERSE(REPLACE(@Url, '\', '/'))) - 1)) as PageName
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to use the substring function:

```
select substring(link from '[0-9]+')
from your_table;
```

This assumes that there is exactly one "number" in the URL.